# Check whether a process is running and terminate it if it's exceeded time limit

Tags: batch-file

So I'm working a project that make competitive judger from batch file, and it works well with correct and incorrect answer. But I stuck with my problem when I try to measure time execution this code. I used timeout and taskkill to delay it for an amount of time, and kill it if didn't finish.

But I faced two problem:

- My code process can be killed twice, and it can crash my batch file.
- It denied my input and output file, so I can't compare my file for verdict.

So how can I measure time, kill a process on Windows and get rid all of my problem?

Here is my code:

- main.bat

```
@echo off

:init
set home=%cd%
chcp 65001>nul
set total=0
set pass=0

:input
set /p user="Enter username: "
if not exist .\submits\%user% (
    echo [[91mERROR[0m] Invalid username.
    pause 0
    exit /b 1
)
set /p prob="Problem: "
if not exist .\problems\%prob% (
    echo [[91mERROR[0m] Invalid problem.
    pause 0
    exit /b 1
)
if not exist .\submits\%user%\%prob%.cpp (
    echo [[91mERROR[0m] User haven't submited this problem yet.
    pause 0
    exit /b 1
)

:judge
rem **compile file, setup for judging**
echo [[93mJury[0m] Judging problem %prob% from user %user%...
if exist result.log del /q result.log
cd submits\%user%
g++ %prob%.cpp -o %prob%.o -std=c++14 -O2
if not errorlevel 0 (
    echo [91mERROR[0m Compile failed...
    pause 0
    exit /b 1
)
move %prob%.o "%home%">nul
cd %home%\problems\%prob%\tests
for /d %%i in ("*") do (
    set /a total+=1
    rem echo [[93mJury[0m] Test %%i...
    copy "%%i\*.txt" "%home%">nul
    cd %home%
    ren out.txt ans.txt
    rem more ans.txt
    echo|set /p=Test %%i: >>result.log
    judge %prob%.o
    if errorlevel 0 set /a pass+=1
    del /q *.txt
    cd %home%\problems\%prob%\tests
)
cd %home%
echo [[92mOK[0m] Judging completed, user passed %pass%/%total% test(s), please check result.log for more detail.
del /q %prob%.o
pause 0
```

- judge.bat

```
rem @echo off

start %1
timeout /t 1 /nobreak
taskkill /im %1 /f
rem echo %errorlevel%
if not errorlevel 128 (
    echo TLE.>>result.log
    exit /b 1
)
fc /a /w out.txt ans.txt>nul && (
    echo Correct.>>result.log
    exit /b 0
) || (
    echo Wrong Answer.>>result.log
    exit /b 1
)
```

(I know my English is so bad, so I can't explain all of my problem, if you have any question, feel free to ask me, I will answer for you)

Answer (score 1):

In

```
echo|set /p=Test %%i: >>result.log
judge %prob%.o
if errorlevel 0 set /a pass+=1
```

You are executing `judge` which appears to be a batch file.

You need

```
CALL judge %prob%.o
```

in order that processing will continue in your `main` procedure after `judge` ends. As it is, processing will be switched to `judge.bat` and end when `judge.bat` ends.

```
if errorlevel 0 set /a pass+=1
```

`IF ERRORLEVEL n` is TRUE if the runtime (ie. current) `errorlevel` is n **or greater than n**. `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` is therefore always true. `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1` is a test for errorlevel=0.

Hope this helps a bit - not *really* sure about your other problems.